# How do you configure the lock screen in Ubuntu Phone?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lock-screen, clock

I just bought the bq Ubuntu Phone. I wondered if it is possible (and how) to configure the lock screen in the Ubuntu Phone, for example which kind of statistics to display or even better how to visualize time inside the central circle (the cover ubuntu edition has a hole to see precisely this circle so it would be great to see the time there).

Comment: What does the circle represent? I have a marker on mine at about the 8 o clock position?

Comment: Is it the date? 23/31 today?

Answer (score 3):

The dial on the lock screen shows data sources from various apps (telegram, phone, etc...) and also shows the current day of the month.

You can change the lock screen background in developer mode. 
You will need to remount the root partition in read-write mode and then you can change the lock screen background which is located at /usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.jpg to whatever you like.

Steps:

- Enable developer mode (System settings > About this phone > Developer mode)
- Open a shell (Either download terminal app or use adb shell on your computer when phone is connected and set up to use adb.
- Remount root partition in read-write mode `sudo mount -o remount,rw /`
- Overwrite /usr/share/unity8/graphics/phone_background.jpg to any other jpg on your device (Size of original pic is 1080x1920 so keep that in mind as not sure how it scales)

If you feel like changing your ringtone to something other than the standard ringtones you can add ogg media files to /usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/ringtones

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, the only customization option that the lock screen offers is the ability to change its background. You can do that by going to the Settings App -> Background and then choosing a picture. You can also double-tab the circle in the lock screen to see other statistics.

Other customization options might be implemented in future versions of Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: Let's hope they will add customizations, like the ability to see notifications there or the content of some scope, like weather or news...

Comment: Items such as the weather and local news/breaking news would be good to see. Also people may not know about the tapping on the date circle, so a scrolling feed would be good that people could tailor to their needs and wants.